# Get the sum from ASCII array

Tags: javascript

Write a function that accepts an array as argument. The function should loop through the array element and accumulate the sum of ASCII value of each character in each element and return the total.

```
function ASCIISuma(array) {
    let suma = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let char_code = array[i].charCodeAt(0);
        suma += char_code;
    }
    return suma;
}
```

[image]

It always shows me incorrect results.

Comment: Remember: don't post pictures of code, [post the code](/help/how-to-ask) (using the code markup that you're already using).

Comment: you're not sending strings to the function, and you're only summing the first character in each element, and you're not even sending an array to the function, you're sending multiple arguments rather than a single array as an argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only adding up the values of the *first* character of each element. To add them all:

```
function ASCIISuma(array) {
    let suma = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for ( let j=0; j < array[i].length; j++ ) {
            let char_code = array[i].charCodeAt(j);
            suma += char_code;
         }
      }
    }
    return suma;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Function to return the sum
of the ascii values of the characters
which are present at prime positions

```
    function isPrime(n){

       if (n == 0 || n == 1)
         return false;
         for (let i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
            if (n % i == 0)
               return false;

        return true;
    }



    function sumAscii(str, n){

       let sum = 0;

       // For every character
       for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {

           // If current position is prime
           // then add the ASCII value of the
           // character at the current position
           if (isPrime(i + 1))
              sum += str.charCodeAt(i);
       }

       return sum;

    }

let str = "geeksforgeeks";
let n = str.length;

document.write(sumAscii(str, n));
```

Comment: Since the question is pretty basic, it might be best to simplify your answer to make it directly address the question.  Specifically, the introduction of checking prime numbers isn't necessary, and could confuse beginners.